# Update PST File With Newer Emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, pst

I exported my Exchange email to a pst file then I got a new pc.
In the meantime I have about 2 months of extra emails.

Can I connect this pst file to Outlook and have Exchange update it with the last 2 months of data or do I have to download the whole set of emails again?

Does it matter what order I connect Outlook to exchange and add the pst file to Outlook?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My Exchange account is over 2GB so, based on the time this took to download and manually spot checking the resultant emails, this seemed to be a way to "synchronize", even though it isn't explicitly mentioned as such.

I connected Outlook to Exchange but ticked **off** "Use Cached Exchange Mode".

[image: Tick off Use Cached Exchange Mode]

I then did export to pst and selected the **existing** pst file (I had a backup just in case it went pear shaped). I was also sure to click Do not export duplicate items.

[image: Do not export duplicate items]

The process finished quite fast on my slow connection and the pst file grew by an appropriate amount.

<sub><sub>Images courtesy of Google Search!</sub></sub>

Comment: Care to explain the down votes?

Answer (score -1):

You can either open a PST file or import it. To be on the safe side you should connect Outlook to Exchange, wait for the mail to be pulled down from the server, then open the PST within the profile and drag and drop whatever is missing into the Exchange mailbox.